# Uncertain about 'is' behavior with nHibernate Proxies

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, proxies

I have a situation where I need to determine whether or not an inherited class is a specific inherited class, but the type expected in the model is the base class, and it is stored using `nHibernate`/`Fluent nHibernate` using a `Table Per Concrete Class` Hierarchy. So my structure looks a bit like this..

```
class Mutation : Entity {
   virtual Aspect Aspect { get; set; }
   virtual Measurement Measurement { get; set; }
}

abstract class Measurement : Entity {
   // does nothing on its own, really.
}

class Numeric : Measurement {
   virtual int Value { get; set; }
   // may have some other properties
}

class Observable : Measurement {
  virtual Aspect Aspect { get; set; }
}
```

So basically, what is going on here is this. `Mutation` expects to be pointed to a type of data, and a Measured change (there could be other ways to change the data, not just flat numerics). So then I would have an object that merely expects an `IList<Mutation>` and map each subsequent type of `Measurement` to its own specific table, sharing the `Identity` with the base `Measurement` class. That works fine so far.

Now an `Observable` is different in that it does not store its own value, but rather it points again to another `Aspect` that may have its own set of mutations and changes. The idea is that the value will always be retrieved from the intended source, and not saved as a flat value in the database. (There is a reason for wanting this behavior that is beyond the scope of this question)

So then, my thought was basically to put in an evaluation like this ..

```
foreach(var measurement in list) {
   if(measurement is Observable){
      // then we know to lookup the other value
   }
}
```

That didn't work. I still get the proxied result of just `MeasurementProxy`. But the same code works fine in a standalone `C#` application without the use of nHibernate, so I feel a great deal of confidence that the issue is with the proxy.

I then added the following method to my base `Entity` class...

```
        /// <summary>
        /// Unwrap the type from whatever proxy it may be
        /// behind, returning the actual .NET <typeparamref name="System.Type"/>.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>
        /// A pure <typeparamref name="System.Type"/> that is no longer proxied.
        /// </returns>
        public virtual Type Unwrap() {
            return GetType();
        }
```

Now if I do a `Console.WriteLine(measurement.Unwrap());` I get the right type, but the same evaluation ...

```
foreach(var measurement in list) {
   if(measurement.Unwrap() is Observable){
      // then we know to lookup the other value
   }
}
```

still does not function. It never runs. Can anyone help me out here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `Unwrap()` returns a `Type`, so `measurement.Unwrap() is Observable` will always be `false`, and `measurement.Unwrap() is Type` would always be `true`.

Use the [typeof](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58918ffs.aspx) operator and reference equality instead:

```
if (measurement.Unwrap() == typeof(Observable)) {
    // Then we know to lookup the other value.
}
```

Comment: So simple, yet I would have never thought to try that. Thank you, that is indeed what was going wrong. Is this a reasonable approach for trying to form a reference and a behaviour based on class type? Or am I just missing the right answer entirely?

Comment: I will accept your answer in 7 minutes when Stack Overflow lets me.

Comment: @Ciel, thanks. Unfortunately, I'm not familiar enough with NHibernate to tell if this is actually the best way to solve your root problem... It should work though, so it might be a reasonable approach :)

Comment: Thanks, again. I've posted a more detailed question about the actual design practice of what I am doing here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6707011/referencial-data-lookup-with-nhibernate

Answer (score 0):

The check in Hamidi answer is not enough. As soon as you add some lazy properties into your mapping, for example:

```
<property name="Description" type="StringClob" not-null="false" lazy="true"/>
```

the Unwrap method will fail, because for the types that employ lazy properties, the objects are always proxy, and the check

```
if (measurement.Unwrap() == typeof(Observable)) {
    // Then we know to lookup the other value.
}
```

will fail because Unwrap will return the type of Proxy, not the expected type.

I use following methods for checking entity types:

```
public virtual Type GetEntityType()
{
    var type = GetType();
    // Hack to avoid problem with some types that always be proxy. 
    // Need re-evaluate when upgrade to NH 3.3.3
    return type.Name.EndsWith("Proxy") ? type.BaseType : type;
}

public virtual bool IsOfType<T>()
{
    return typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(GetEntityType());
}
```

and the check becomes:

```
if (measurement.IsOfType<Observable>()) {
    // Then we know to lookup the other value.
}
```

As you see in the code comment, this is a hack for NH 3.1 and Castle Proxy: Castle Dynamic Proxy types always end with Proxy, so I exploited this signature to detect if the object is proxy or not. My project is still stuck with NH3.1 so I'm not sure what changes the method will need with NH3.3.